# How to make a proxy server in C++ using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, proxy

I'm making a web application fuzzer and for my proxy server, I'm using opensource code (for now) developed by a guy named Alex Ott. I've noticed though that when I make requests from some websites that those don't get captured so I really want to write my own proxy in C++ but I have absolutely no idea where to start. Could someone explain it to me?

The end goal is really to be able to capture and write every request that comes through the proxy to a file, which I'm already doing but the proxy server I have now isn't catch all this requests, ones I know to be there.

Edit: Since the question was unclear, here it is: I want to know what the code is for a proxy server written in C++ using the Boost extension libraries. Same question for the past four months.

Comment: I think you mean a proxy server?

Comment: I'm afraid to ask 'what have you tried?'. if you have no idea whatsoever you can start by reading Advanced Unix Network Programming VOL1.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use an existing proxy. Here is one that has proved useful for me when doing fuzzing, and it supports writing to a file: http://www.parosproxy.org/

Comment: Yeah Proxy server. And @aftnix I haven't really tried much as far as network programming goes. I don't really understand it at all. I've been using the ones I've found that are built in Boost but I think I'll start reading that book.

Comment: Just two months ago I just had to implement a proxy for a very specific use case, and therefore couldn't use a off-the-shelf existing one.  It's relatively simple.  Listen on one address, open another, data transferred from one gets forwarded to the other.  The entirety of the one I wrote is using `boost::asio`, and a simple one can be done in < 500 lines of code.

Comment: @Chad, that's exactly what I want to do! Using boost::asio and everything. I get how to do it in theory but practically implementing it is where, well where I don't know squat.

Comment: Hmmm, I found an [Alex Ott](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott) on SO. Same one?

Comment: Well @shadow, have a look at my answer.  Should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, here's a somewhat functional example to get you started.  It forwards between two connections.  Note that this simple example won't work for a web browser, as the client will attempt to make several connections, and this example only listens on one.  Using this as a (very simple) base, you should be able to make some progress.

The interesting stuff happens in `handle_read`, which is the callback that is executed when data is received.  This function forwards the data between sockets.  Notice that when we originally called it for the "local" and "remote" connections that the order we passed the sockets in is reversed (`read_from` and `write_to`).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service& io_service()
{
   static boost::asio::io_service svc;
   return svc;
}

char local_data[1024] = {0};
char remote_data[1024] = {0};

void handle_read(
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& read_from,
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& write_to,
   char* read_buffer,
   size_t bytes,
   const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
   // this function is called whenever data is received

   // for debugging purposes, show the data in the console window
   // or write to file, or whatever...
   std::string data(read_buffer, read_buffer + bytes);    
   std::cout << data << "\n";

   // forward the received data on to "the other side"    
   write_to.send(
      boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer, bytes));

   // read more data from "this side"
   read_from.async_read_some(
      boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer, 1024),
      boost::bind(handle_read, boost::ref(read_from), boost::ref(write_to), read_buffer, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   if(argc == 5)
   {
      boost::asio::io_service::work w(io_service());

      boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, (&io_service())));

      // extract the connection information from the command line
      boost::asio::ip::address local_address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(argv[1]);
      uint16_t local_port = boost::lexical_cast<uint16_t>(argv[2]);
      boost::asio::ip::address remote_address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(argv[3]);
      uint16_t remote_port = boost::lexical_cast<uint16_t>(argv[4]);

      boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint local_ep(local_address, local_port);
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint remote_ep(remote_address, remote_port);

      // start listening on the "local" socket -- note this does not
      // have to be local, you could in theory forward through a remote device
      // it's called "local" in the logical sense    
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor listen(io_service(), local_ep);
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket local_socket(io_service());
      listen.accept(local_socket);

      // open the remote connection
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket remote_socket(io_service());
      remote_socket.open(remote_ep.protocol());
      remote_socket.connect(remote_ep);

      // start listening for data on the "local" connection
      local_socket.async_receive(
         boost::asio::buffer(local_data, 1024),
         boost::bind(handle_read, boost::ref(local_socket), boost::ref(remote_socket), local_data, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

      // also listen for data on the "remote" connection
      remote_socket.async_receive(
         boost::asio::buffer(remote_data, 1024),
         boost::bind(handle_read, boost::ref(remote_socket), boost::ref(local_socket), remote_data, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

      t.join();
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "proxy <local ip> <port> <remote ip> <port>\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```